# Passing a reference to a thread function without copying

Tags: c#, lambda, thread-safety

Is the followng use of threading correct:

```
    FT[] ft = new FT[iota_Delta_tau];
    Thread[] t = new Thread[iota_Delta_tau];
    for (int i = 0; i < iota_Delta_tau; i++)
    {
        int copy_i = i;
        t[i] = new Thread(() => ThreadNewFt(ref ft[i], copy_i));
        t[i].Start();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < iota_Delta_tau; i++)
        t[i].Join();
```

I use `copy_i` instead of `i` because it is used in the lambda expression for the new thread. But I worry about `ref ft[i]`. I cannot send a copy of it because it is a ref. I worry the same thing as this happens:
[MutiThreading - Index was outside the bounds of the array Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51904914)

Comment: Have you executed, and run your program? have you come across any errors or unexpected results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The copy is needed only if you want to provide a new value on each iteration which isn't true for `ft` I believe. The only thing to correct is `ref ft[copy_i]` instead of `ref ft[i]`. However using TPL would be more efficient and neat option:

```
        Parallel.For(0, iota_Delta_tau, i => ThreadNewFt(ref ft[i], i));
```

instead of all code above.